# Display one post in different formats conditionally

Tags: page-template, post-content

I think I just coded myself into a corner. I am setting up a page with an image. The image is an imagemap with lots of links. When you click on the link, it opens a post in a colorbox. So far I have managed to get this part working using a combination of the Lightbox Plus and Post Template plugins.

Unfortunately this involves assigning each post to a specific template. The template simply removes the title/image/menu. But this permanently alters the post display. I need to post to still show the full header if it is accessed through the normal menu or from a Google search.

How can I display a post differently based on how it is accessed? OR - how can I insert just the post content into the colorbox window without using a custom page or post template?

Comment: Can you please add relevant code to your question.

Comment: I really don't have any yet. I'm using two plugins, and the two pages I added are kinda what I'm trying to avoid altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A potential solution would be to first get rid of the Post Template plugin and just use the default `single.php` to render single post views.

Then add a get variable onto the end of your imagemap links, so they're something like `domain.com/post-name/?view=lightbox`

Then filter the `single_template` to load your lightbox view template when the GET var is detected:

```
function wpa_lightbox_single( $template ){
    if( isset( $_GET['view'] ) )
        $template = locate_template( 'lightbox-view.php' );

    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'wpa_lightbox_single' );
```

Comment: oh man - I'm going to have to brush up on my PHP aren't I? *sigh*

Comment: Rats - tried to edit and went over the 5 minute restriction. Meant to add: "Oh well, it was inevitable. But seriously, Milo - thank you. This looks promising. The Lightbox Plus Colorbox plugin requires adding a class variable to the link. Would this potentially bypass that? Also, would this function be something that I added directly to single.php?"

Comment: So I added the function code into functions.php and this didn't seem to work. Should the code go into single.php instead?

Comment: the function goes in `functions.php`. your links will still need the lightbox class added as well as the appended `view` `GET` variable. You can test if it's working on its own by viewing a single post, then adding `?view=lightbox` directly to the URL in your browser. You'll also need to change `lightbox-view.php` to the name of the template you want to load in the lightbox.

Comment: I kept your code as is - added it to functions.php - renamed my content-only page template to lightbox-view.php - disabled the Post Template plugin. Unfortunately it seems to be using single.php with or without the 'view' variable. Here is the link to the test page - all three links have the class variable for the lightbox plugin. http://staging.vagabondians.com/sample-page/

Comment: On that test page the first two links are regular, the third has the `view` `GET` variable added. As you can see, all three have identical styling with the full header/masthead.

Comment: the `lightbox-view.php` has to be in the root of your theme's directory. if I try to visit the file directly I get a 404, so I'm guessing it's in a subfolder within your theme.

Comment: Aha! Yes, I renamed a file I was trying to use as a page/post template, so it was in that directory. It works now! Kudos to you Milo. Now for the imagemap parts. THAT should be easy...